# PHP - How to dynamically add array to Object request

Tags: php, rest, api, jira-agile, php-curl

I am doing Jira REST API calls and I am wondering how I can dynamically add more than one component to the components field using REST API in PHP. I have the following code, works when I set it static, but not sure how to do it dynamically.

**Example of static component set:**

```
$data = array(

'fields' => array(

    'project' => array(

        'key' => $rowAnswers["Key"]

    ),
    'summary' =>  $rowAnswers["Summary"],

    'description' => $rowAnswers["Description"],

    'issuetype' => array(
        'name' => $rowAnswers["IssueType"]
    ),

    'components' => array(
        array(
            "name" => "component1"
        ),
        array(
            "name" => "component2"
        )
    )
),
);
```

My array that I want to replace the static content with:

```
$components = explode(",", $rowAnswers["Components"]);
        $arr = array();
        foreach($components as $value){
            $array = array("name"=>$value);
            array_push($arr,$array);
        }
```

Replacing

```
'components' => array(
    array(
        "name" => "component1"
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "component2"
    )
)
```

with

```
'components' => [
                    $arr
                ]
```

doesn't work, I get:

```
"{"error":false,"error_msg":"","data":"{\"errorMessages\":[],\"errors\":{\"components\":\"expected Object\"}}"}"
```

I see on an api call to get a request it looks like this:

```
[components] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => component1
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => component2
                    )

            )
```

But I am unsure how to transform an array into this type of object or request in PHP. Calling with PHP-cURL and json_encoding the data it sends.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you view your api response ? `json_decode()` ??

Comment: Yes, I am using PHP cURL to both get the data as well as create. the viewing is done by: $result = curl_exec($ch); json_decode($result); @HassanAhmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I had to do the following:

When creating the array from the DB:

```
$components = explode(",", $rowAnswers["Components"]);
        $arr = array();
        foreach($components as $value){
            $array = json_decode(json_encode(array("name"=>$value)), FALSE);
            array_push($arr,$array);
        }
```

Then to set the component in the request:

```
'components' => $arr
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to decode your json as associative array by setting the second parameter to true

check out the [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)

> assoc
>
> ```
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.
> ```

Comment: I am not having an issue when reading the data, It is when I am sending the data via php-curl in a rest api call to create a request. I need to have the currently static component array use the dynamically set array from a DB.

Comment: This is an example: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/9379363/how-to-add-component-while-creating-an-issue-via-jira-rest-api

Comment: as i get from the link you have provided that you have to send the data as php an associative array not objects array , your response seems to be an object array not an associative array , decoding the json as associative array may help! , if that doesn't make a sense please provide more details to your question

Comment: I need to replace this section in my request: 
'components' => array(
        array(
            "name" => "component1"
        ),
        array(
            "name" => "component2"
        )
    )

with the data from my dynamic array from the DB.

'components' => [$arr] doesn't work, not sure what I need.

Comment: in your code , try to replace the static part by : `'components' => $arr` , and for debugging purpose , print your array to check if it follow the jira request standards or not

Comment: I did that before and got an error, so I also added $array = json_decode(json_encode(array("name"=>$value)), FALSE); when creating the array of arrays, now it works. thanks.